# App React Native con Expo no puede tener permisos en Android

Tags: react-native

Tengo una app que cuando estoy corriendo con Expo, los permisos funcionan bien y me aparece el cuadro de dialogo para aceptarlos o denegarlos. Sin embargo cuando genero el apk con expo build:android y la instalo en mi telefono, la app no me pregunta por los permisos. En administrador de aplicaciones mi app no muestra ningun permiso que haya sido aceptado o rechazado por lo que no puedo habilitarlos manualmente.

Este es mi App.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "dev-1",
    "slug": "dev-1",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android", "web"],
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.fernandoAzarias.tenedores",
      "permissions": ["CAMERA_ROLL", "LOCATION"],
      "versionCode": 2
    },
    "description": "An app just for learn React Native"
  }
}
```

Esto es una parte del codigo que obtiene los permisos

```
const changeAvatar = async () => {
    const resultPermissions = await Permissions.askAsync(
      Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL
    );
    console.log(resultPermissions);
    setLog([...log, resultPermissions]);
    if (resultPermissions.granted) {
      const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3]
      });
```

setLog guarda el objeto de los permisos, lo cual me permite mostrarlos en pantalla. Estoy recibiendo esto como respuesta:

```
{
  canAskAgain: false
  expires: never,
  granted: false
  Permissions: {
    cameraRoll: {
      canAskAgain: false
      expires: never
      granted: false
      status: denied
    }
  }
}
```

Claramente la app no tiene permisos, pero en administrador de aplicaciones la app no tiene ningun permiso y no muestra nada, por lo cual no puedo habilitar deshabilitar.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

de mi experiencia con expo en primer lugar depende del sdk, después debes tomar en cuenta la lista de permisos que debe tener cuando ya se trata de un app compilada, como indica en la documentación.

> The permission type for photo and video taking. Android: it requires
> the CAMERA permission in your manifest.

En otras palabras:
["CAMERA_ROLL"] sirve siempre y cuando estés en desarrollo,
["CAMERA"] sirve cuando ya esté lista para "produccion"

La lista de permisos la encuentras aquí:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#permissionscamera

también puedes revisar los permisos que un dispositivo android tiene aquí.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#CAMERA